# rake aborted! Validation failed: User can't be blank for seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Why doesn't the user get assigned when I do this?

```
u1 = User.create( :username => "user1", :password => "testing", :email =>  "user1@email.com", :time_zone => "Tokyo")
u2 = User.create( :username => "user2", :password => "testing", :email =>  "user2@email.com", :time_zone => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
u3 = User.create( :username => "user3", :password => "testing", :email =>  "user3@email.com", :time_zone => "Singapore") # User that adds Private stuff only.

o1 = Owner.create!( :name => "Owner A", :about => "", :user_id => User.find_by_username("user1"), :private => false, without_protection: true )
o2 = Owner.create!( :name => "Owner B", :about => "", :user_id => User.find_by_username("user2"), :private => false, without_protection: true )
o3 = Owner.create!( :name => "Private Owner", :about => "", :user_id => User.find_by_username("user3"), :private => true, without_protection: true )
```

I get the error:

```
$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
Validation failed: User can't be blank

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What other ways is their, that I can assign the user id then?

**UPDATE**

Owner.rb

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :about, :private
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :locations
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_inclusion_of :private, :in => [true, false]
  validates_length_of :name, :in => 3...50, :allow_blank => true
end
```

So far I've tried:

```
:user_id => User.find_by_username("user1")
:user_id => u1
:user_id => u1.id
:user => User.find_by_username("user1")
:user => u1
```

**UPDATE 2**

This works but only saves `user_id = 1` for all of my Owners:

```
o1 = Owner.new( :name => "Owner A", :about => "", :private => false )
o1.user_id = u1
o1.save!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have not included the code for your models, from the validation error it would seem that you have a validation for presence of `user` in your `Owner` model. In your `Owner.create!` lines, you are passing in `user_id`. Try changing it to this:

```
o1 = Owner.create!( :name => "Owner A", :about => "", :user => User.find_by_username("user1"), :private => false, without_protection: true )
```

Or, alternatively since you have just created these users, you could just do:

```
o1 = Owner.create!( :name => "Owner A", :about => "", :user => u1, :private => false, without_protection: true )
```

As a side note, you can pass in an association in two ways, either by passing its id (`:user_id => user.id`) or by passing the actual instance (`:user => @user`). Rails validations are very picky though so if you are validating on `user` it will look for `user`, and if you're validating on `user_id` it will look for `user_id`.

Comment: Ah, I see, didn't know that about the validations. I posted my `Owner` model and what I've tried so far.

Comment: Try changing your validation to `validates_presence_of :user`.

Comment: I tried changing the validation with all of the ones above but still no luck. I just don't understand this. My `User` model is correct, it has the `has_many` association in it.

Comment: Oh you're missing `user` (or `user_id` whichever you use) in the arguments to `attr_accessible`, try adding it there.

Comment: Although I should say that it's generally not good to allow the user to be mass assigned. In general it's better to create a new instance, assign the user and then call `save`.

Comment: Isn't their another way to assign the user_id by force instead of making is mass assignable?

Comment: Yes: use `Owner.new!` instead of `Owner.create!`, and leave out the user from the arguments. Then just assign `o1.user = u1`, and finally `o1.save!`.

Comment: `o1.user = u1` threw the same error. I also couldn't use `new!` as it gives an `undefined method`. I used `o1.user_id = u1` and it worked but when I do `o2.user_id = u2`, it stills saves for `user_id = u1` instead of `u2`. i.e. Their all saved for the same user.

Comment: Oh sorry, there shouldn't be a `!` on the end of new, my mistake. Also your assignment should be: `o1.user_id = u1.id` **OR** `o1.user = u1`, but **not** `o1.user_id = u1`. You have to be careful about matching the types of things you are assigning, otherwise weird things will happen (here I think ruby is converting the presence of any instance to the integer 1).

Comment: OK, I understand that now. I changed my validation to `validates_presence_of :user` in order to use  `o1.user = u1` but it doesn't save a user to the owner. If I do `u1.id`, it will throw the original error. This a pain in the ass.....

Comment: OK! It's working now. I just tried `User.find_by_username("user1") and user2` and it assigned correctly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! You just have to be very systematic in your debugging and you'll find the problem.